# Can't show html layout in yahoo mail however, my code below is proper

Tags: php, html, email

I can't send html email through PHP.

in yahoo email, it is showing text based email. How can i make email to show normal html based.

**Output of my email in yahoo mail:**

```
<html><head></head><body><h2>test heading</h2><br><table><tr><td>Color / Pattern: </td><td>yellow</td></tr></table></body></table>
```

**PHP code:**

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: '.$email."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$reply_to."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
$message = "<html><head></head><body><h2>test heading</h2><br><table><tr><td>Color / Pattern: </td><td>yellow</td></tr></table></body></table>";
mail($mail_to, $subject, $message, $header);
```

Comment: Give up on making your own multipart MIME handlers for e-mail... it's nearly an impossible task to get right.  Use an existing package like PHPMailer or similar.

Comment: @Brad that's also answered there.

Comment: It does matter @mak, there are tons of repeated questions like yours on SO, just search and I'm sure you'll find the answer quickly

Comment: @Brad My bad, I've deleted the comment.

Comment: The HTML in the message is incorrect (there's a stray `</table>` at the end), so maybe some mail clients choke on that.